# Asp.net with C# and Mono on Debian - Nginx / g-wan

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, nginx, debian

i'm developing a web application in C# and Asp.net.

Acutally i'm looking for using an efficient and performant running System.

Well the Question ist now:

1. Option: Asp.net & c# & Mono & Debian & Nginx
2. Option: Asp.net & c# & Mono & Debian & G-Wan
3. Option: Asp.net & c# & Windows Server & IIS

Which one would you select and why?

The Application is just for showing some Stuff. There is nothing to download.

Many thanks for your help.